# Count number of matches using regex.h in C

Tags: c, regex

I'm using the POSIX regular expressions `regex.h` in C to count the number of appearances of a phrase in an English-language text fragment. 
But the return value of [`regexec(...)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Matching-POSIX-Regexps.html) only tells if a match was found or not. So I tried to use the `nmatch` and `matchptr` to find distinct appearances, but when I printed out the matches from `matchptr`, I just received the first index of first phrase appear in my text.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_MATCHES 20 //The maximum number of matches allowed in a single string

void match(regex_t *pexp, char *sz) {
    regmatch_t matches[MAX_MATCHES];
    if (regexec(pexp, sz, MAX_MATCHES, matches, 0) == 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_MATCHES; i++)
        printf("\"%s\" matches characters %d - %d\n", sz, matches[i].rm_so, matches[i].rm_eo);
    } 
    else {
        printf("\"%s\" does not match\n", sz);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rv;
    regex_t exp;
    rv = regcomp(&exp, "(the)", REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE);
    if (rv != 0) {
        printf("regcomp failed\n");
    }
    match(&exp, "the cat is in the bathroom.");
    regfree(&exp);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make this code to report both of the two distinct matches of regular expression `(the)` in the string `the cat is in the bathroom`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've understood the meaning of `pmatch` incorrectly. It is not used for getting repeated pattern matches. It is used to get the location of the one match and its possible subgroups. As Linux manual for `regcomp(3)` says:

> The offsets of the subexpression starting at the `i`th open
> parenthesis are stored in `pmatch[i]`.  The entire  regular  expression's  match  addresses  are  stored  in
> `pmatch[0]`.   (Note  that  to  return the offsets of N subexpression matches, `nmatch` must be at least `N+1`.)
> Any unused structure elements will contain the value `-1`.

If you have the regular expression `this (\w+) costs (\d+) USD`, there are 2 capturing groups in parentheses `(\w+)` and `(\d+)`; now if `nmatch` was set to at least 3, `pmatch[0]` would contain the start and end indices of the whole match, `pmatch[1]` start and end for the  `(\w+)` group and `pmatch[2]` for the `(\d+)` group.

---

The following code should print the ranges of consecutive matches, if any (the beginning of each range is the offset of the *first character* inside the match, and the end of the range is the first character *after the match*, matching the `rm_so`, `rm_eo` usage); or the string `"<the input string>" does not contain a match` if the pattern *never* matches.

It is carefully constructed so that it works for a zero-length regular expression as well (an empty regular expression, or say regular expression `#?` will match at each character position including after the last character; 28 matches of that regular expression would be reported for input `the cat is in the bathroom.`)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void match(regex_t *pexp, char *sz) {
    // we just need the whole string match in this example    
    regmatch_t whole_match;

    // we store the eflags in a variable, so that we can make
    // ^ match the first time, but not for subsequent regexecs
    int eflags = 0;
    int match = 0;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t length = strlen(sz);

    while (regexec(pexp, sz + offset, 1, &whole_match, eflags) == 0) {
        // do not let ^ match again.
        eflags = REG_NOTBOL;
        match = 1;
        printf("range %zd - %zd matches\n",
               offset + whole_match.rm_so,
               offset + whole_match.rm_eo);

        // increase the starting offset
        offset += whole_match.rm_eo;

        // a match can be a zero-length match, we must not fail
        // to advance the pointer, or we'd have an infinite loop!
        if (whole_match.rm_so == whole_match.rm_eo) {
            offset += 1;
        }

        // break the loop if we've consumed all characters. Note
        // that we run once for terminating null, to let
        // a zero-length match occur at the end of the string.
        if (offset > length) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! match) {
        printf("\"%s\" does not contain a match\n", sz);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rv;
    regex_t exp;
    rv = regcomp(&exp, "(the)", REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE);
    if (rv != 0) {
        printf("regcomp failed\n");
    }
    match(&exp, "the cat is in the bathroom.");
    regfree(&exp);
    return 0;
}
```

---

P.S., the parentheses in your regex `(the)` are unnecessary in this case; you could just write `the` (and your initial confusion of getting 2 matches at same position was because you'd get one match for `(the)` and one submatch for `the`, had you not have had these parentheses, your code would have printed the location of first match only once).

Comment: Thank for your explaination, i have understand the meaning of these parameters now, but i also want to know if we have any way to determine the counting number of matches when using regex.h in c, thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much, so the pointer sz can also be used to determine the starting point to regexec next time, i'm understand now, thank you very much :D.

Comment: @huynguyen yeah, with this function it is the only way.

Comment: @huynguyen ahha, fixed the `eflags` thing

Comment: Ok, ensured that it works properly with `^` - only matches in the beginning.

Comment: I think it should be `offset = whole_match.rm_eo;` (not `+=`). I.e. you want to start searching from the end of the previous match, not from the sum of the offsets of the previous matches.

Comment: @dreamlax no, the code is absolutely correct. The `.rm_so` and `.rm_eo` themselves are relative to `sz + offset`, not `sz`.

Comment: Hi. should it be `printf("range %zd - %zd matches\n",
    offset + whole_match.rm_so,
    offset + whole_match.rm_eo -1);
` ?

Comment: @jian depends how you wanna think this :D I am used to Python ranges where the end is considered consistently be the first that does not belong. The regex API seems to agree with this too ;-)